# How do I use a Levenshtein distance function in a sqlite where clause?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite, levenshtein-distance

I'm trying to implement a "Did you mean?" sort of function for a search.

I'm trying to do a query that uses the levenshtein function, which was written in ruby. I was wondering how I could use this function in a sqlite3 query. I was thinking it might be something like this:

`@results = the_db.where('levenshtein(name, ?) <= 3', searchphrase)`

But i'm not sure how to get it to work. Could someone help me out?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11836462/using-levenshtein-distance-ratio-to-compare-2-records This helps?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the `editdist3` function:

> The editdist3 algorithm is a function that computes the minimum edit
>   distance (a.k.a. the Levenshtein distance) between two input strings.

- http://www.sqlite.org/spellfix1.html

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49815419/1422096) is a HOWTO + ready-to-use example for both Windows and Linux.