# How to use editdist3 in sqlite

Tags: sqlite, levenshtein-distance, gentoo

According to an [answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13928405/1534459), in sqlite the Levenshtein distance is implemented in a SQL function called `editdist3`. (Compare also the [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/spellfix1.html))

Now when I try to use it, all I get is an error that it doesn’t exist:

```
╰┄┄> sqlite3
SQLite version 3.11.1 2016-03-03 16:17:53
Enter ".help" for usage hints.
Connected to a transient in-memory database.
Use ".open FILENAME" to reopen on a persistent database.
sqlite> CREATE TABLE test (col1 TEXT);
sqlite> INSERT INTO test VALUES ('foobar');
sqlite> SELECT * FROM test WHERE editdist3(col1, 'f00bar') < 3;
Error: no such function: editdist3
```

I’m using sqlite-3.11.1 on Gentoo Linux with (default) USE flags `icu`, `readline` and `secure-delete`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It turns out `editdist3` is contained in an sqlite extension that has to be loaded explicitly. As I didn’t find it in the Gentoo sqlite package, I also had to build it myself. As the [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/spellfix1.html) says:

> The spellfix1 virtual table is not included in the SQLite amalgamation
>   and is not a part of any standard SQLite build. It is a loadable
>   extension.

First I fetched the source code

```
wget https://sqlite.org/2016/sqlite-src-3110100.zip
unzip sqlite-src-3110100.zip
```

then it has to be compiled

```
gcc -shared -fPIC -Wall -Isqlite-src-3110100 sqlite-src-3110100/ext/misc/spellfix.c -o spellfix.so
```

and finally it can be loaded with

```
.load ./spellfix
```

Note that sqlite automatically appends the extension `.so`.

To use it in python – which was my original intention – the following needs to be done:

```
db = sqlite3.connect(':memory:')

db.enable_load_extension(True)
db.load_extension('./spellfix')
db.enable_load_extension(False)
```

Comment: `fatal error: sqlite3ext.h: No such file or directory`: which library should I install first?  `apt-get install unzip build-essentials` of course, but what else? I've searched `libsqlite` but there are dozains of such packages. Thanks in advance @bodo

Comment: @Basj: I assume you're on a Debian-based distribution. Then the package you need is `libsqlite3-dev`. See e.g. https://packages.debian.org/search?searchon=contents&keywords=sqlite3ext.h&mode=exactfilename&suite=stretch&arch=any

Comment: Thanks a lot @bodo! By the way, I just discovered https://www.debian.org/distrib/packages#search_contents that I didn't know, thanks!

Comment: For future reference: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49815419/1422096) is a detailed HOWTO + ready-to-use example for both Windows and Linux.