# How to compile Sqlite for Windows with a specific module (spellfix1)?

Tags: python, windows, sqlite, compilation

In order to make [Levensthein distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_Distance) (string similary) work with Sqlite on Windows, I either:

- need to find a Sqlite binary version that has [`spellfix1`](http://www.sqlite.org/spellfix1.html) module already included
- or to recompile the whole Sqlite for Windows with this module,
- or to compile just this module.

The final goal is to load it in Python via:

```
import sqlite3
db = sqlite3.connect(':memory:')
db.enable_load_extension(True)
db.load_extension('./spellfix')
db.enable_load_extension(False)
...
c.execute('SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE editdist3(description, "Hello wrld") < 3')
```

**Question:**

Should I recompile the whole Sqlite for Windows, and replace `C:\Python27\DLLs\_sqlite3.pyd` by the new one? If so, how? and is it safe to expect that Python will accept this newly-compiled `_sqlite3.pyd` file?
Or should I keep the old `C:\Python27\DLLs\_sqlite3.pyd` and just compile the external module `spellfix1`? How?

**What I've tried so far**:

- Download https://sqlite.org/2016/sqlite-src-3110100.zip, unzip it
- Run this:

  ```
  call "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat"
  cl ext\misc\spellfix.c
  ```

  > ext\misc\spellfix.c(17) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'sqlite3ext.h': No such file or directory

  Where to find the headers, and where to specify these headers in `cl.exe ...`?

Note: [this is](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36427821/1422096) for Linux but I couldn't do the same on Windows.

Comment: You may find this useful: http://sqlite.1065341.n5.nabble.com/Spellfix-Implementation-td75596.html. I would only compile `spellfix1` with minGW and try to load it first.

Comment: @JacquesGaudin do you think it would work into Python, or should I recompile the whole `sqlite3` python module?

Comment: My guess is that if you can load it in sqlite it will work from python as the `load_extension` method is just a binding to the original C method.

Comment: Luckily I am on a Windows machine and I managed to get MinGw to work. I could compile using `gcc -g -shared spellfix.c -I ~/sqlite-amalgation-3230100/ -o spellfix.dll`. Basically the error you get is msvc trying to find the include files in the amalgation package `sqlite3.h` and `sqlite3ext.h`. Use the `cl /I <path-to-amalgation> ext\misc\spellfix.c`... or something similar!

Comment: @JacquesGaudin Thanks for your answer, I tried with `/I ...`, and it can find the .h now, but it still doesnt work: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49813006/cl-exe-error-d8003-missing-source-filename-when-building-a-sqlite-module

Comment: I got it to work with `cl` and posted the command on your other question.