# cl.exe error D8003 (missing source filename) when building a Sqlite module

Tags: windows, sqlite, visual-c++, cl

I downloaded and unziped https://sqlite.org/2016/sqlite-src-3110100.zip. Then when trying to build as a DLL the extension `spellfix` (it [works](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36427821/1422096) on Linux though) with:

```
call "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat"
cd sqlite-src-3110100
cl /I"src\" ext\misc\spellfix.c /link
```

I get:

```
cl : Command line error D8003 : missing source filename
```

Why?

Comment: For future reference: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49815419/1422096) is a detailed HOWTO + ready-to-use example for both Windows and Linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try:

```
cl /I <path to sqlite amalgation> <path-to-spellfix.c> /link /DLL /OUT:spellfix.dll
```

Comment: Thanks @JacquesGaudin. I tried `cl /I src ext/misc/spellfix.c /link /DLL /OUT:spellfix.dll` and now `sqlite3ext.h` is successfully found but now `Cannot open include file: 'sqlite3.h': No such file or directory`. I double checked in the archive https://sqlite.org/2016/sqlite-src-3110100.zip, and no `sqlite3.h` in it. Why?

Comment: Also I found [here](https://sqlite.org/spellfix1.html) `The spellfix1 virtual table is not included in the SQLite amalgamation`

Comment: All the include files you need are here: https://www.sqlite.org/2018/sqlite-amalgamation-3230100.zip

Comment: Tghe `src` folder doesn't contain the required include files.

Comment: What if you don't have any source, because you are linking obj already built?

Comment: @Sandburg You need to invoke `LINK` directly then, something like `LINK /DLL firsti.obj second.obj third.obj /OUT:spellfix.dll`

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar problem with DBeaver and jdbc driver for SQLite. And hope it will help someone to save some time.

**Problems**:

1. I was not able to load extension spellfix
   I was receiving error "**no such module spellfix1**" upon execution

   select * from table1 where col1 like 'asd%'
2. docs for SQLite are not obvious how to load extension, nor build it (this thread helped me, thank you guys but still it was not obvious since I was not coding for a very long time)

**Solution**:

1. I've downloaded source of sqlite from url below, afterwards done following steps from post above but since i have x64 DBeaver I was receiving error

**SQL error or missing database (%1 is not a valid Win32 application.)**
It was obvious that I need x64 build so the following steps I did:

a) in cmd prompt executed:

```
call "E:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat" amd64
```

**amd64** param is necessary to setup build environment for x64 build

b) afterwards i used cl command:

```
cl /I "<path to sqlite amalgation folder>" "ext\misc\spellfix.c" /link /DLL /OUT:spellfix64.dll
```

cmd prompt was at location where I downloaded latest sqlite source from this [URL](https://www.sqlite.org/src/info?name=trunk).
How did I get to that link was also a bit of a adventure :)

2. afterwards put my dll to location and executed **load_extension** command in DBeaver

   `select load_extension('E:/Users/Name/Downloads/SQLite/ext/spellfix64');`

path where i put build version. To be able to build x64 version I needed to build with above comments.

Uhh, one more thing, you need to **enable loading extensions in DBeaver** on connection properties: post is [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/294626/how-do-i-insert-rows-into-a-spatial-table-within-a-geopackage-file-via-a-sql-ins).