# String similarity using inside AutoHotkey withSqlite (Levenshtein distance)

Tags: sqlite, string-comparison, similarity

I am looking for a similarity function in SQLite. 
levenshtein-distance, sorenson, jaccard or jaro_winkler. 
as a windows dll.

I want to use this function if other select fails [select01 ... 6.sql](https://github.com/sl5net/global-IntelliSense-everywhere/tree/master/Source/sql/template)

[I did not succeed with this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49779281/string-similarity-with-python-sqlite-levenshtein-distance-edit-distance/49815419#49815419)

the best would be a finished dll or a function I do not know yet (different to searching with like).

sometimes I mistype my search slightly.
example: `tootip` istead `tooltip`

Comment: The [spellfix1](https://www.sqlite.org/spellfix1.html) extension module can be useful for such things.

Comment: I have to compile first? i have no experience aas C programmer. I'm just reading a bit here: https://www.sqlite.org/loadext.html maybe there is already a ready-made DLL elsewhere

Comment: Yes, you'd have to compile it as a shared library and load that into a sqlite connection.

Comment: okay. i try. I'll make it that will take a bit of time. I have the first error after applying this line: 
C:\Program Files\mingw-w64\x86_64-4.9.2-posix-seh-rt_v3-rev1\mingw64\bin\gcc.exe -g -shared c:\fre\spellfix.c -o c:\fre\spellfix.dll No #include "sqlite3ext.h" I'll find that soon, too

Comment: i took all missed files from go-sqlite3. here: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mattn/go-sqlite3/master/sqlite3-binding.h and https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mattn/go-sqlite3/master/sqlite3ext.h it has compiled.

Comment: SELECT load_extension('spellfix.dll'); gives me: [1] [SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database

Comment: I've only used the C API to load modules (or `.load` in the shell program), but you should leave out the file extension. Not sure if that's relevant for that error message though.

Comment: i tried: c:\...\Source\Lib\x64>sqlite3.dll .load ./SpellFixExt.dll

Comment: i found and run a sqlite3.exe. wrote .load ./SpellFixExt.dll
two screenshots: https://imgur.com/a/YFgJVcb and got error