# Edit Distance in NodeSQlite in Arabic

Tags: sql, node.js, sqlite, arabic

How can I check the edit distance between Arabic words in Node SQlite?

For example, to check the edit distance between `رِحْلَة` and `رحلة`

Comment: Have you tried to calculate the [Levenshtein distance](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13928405/5156280) ?

Comment: how do I use the editDist for the query tho? @TGrif